How to make a Runnable class a Spring Boot Component whose bean will be created dynamically?
I want to create a Spring Boot Component named GameSessionRunner that implements the Runnable interface. During its creation, GameSessionRunner needs an object of SudokuGame, which will be dynamically created through a REST API call.
Once the SudokuGame object is created, I want Spring to create a new instance of GameSessionRunner by injecting the SudokuGame object into its constructor.
Then, I want to create an object of GameSession. This object will hold a reference to the GameSessionRunner and a Thread object for running the GameSessionRunner.
Finally, the GameSession object will be saved to the GameSessionRepository based on its gameId. This will allow me to retrieve any GameSession later using its gameId.
These are the classes:
GameController :
@RestController
@RequestMapping("game-server")
public class GameController {

    @Autowired
    private GameService gameService;

    @Autowired
    private GameSessionService gameSessionService;

    @Autowired
    private NotificationService notificationService;

    @Autowired
    private GameSessionRepository gameSessionRepository;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @PostMapping("/create-game")
    public ResponseEntity<SudokuGame> createGame(@RequestBody CreateGameRequest createGameRequest) {

        SudokuGame game = gameService.createGame(createGameRequest);
                
        //Here instead of creating object of GameSessionRunner using new keyword,
        //I want spring to create it by passing game object.

        GameSessionRunner gameSessionRunner = new GameSessionRunner(game);
        Thread gameThread = new Thread(gameSessionRunner);
        GameSession gameSession = new GameSession(gameSessionRunner, gameThread);

        gameSessionRepository.addGameSession(game.getGameId(), gameSession);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(game , HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}

GameSessionRunner:
public class GameSessionRunner implements Runnable {

    private SudokuGame game;
    private boolean isStopped;
    private boolean isPaused;

    @Autowired
    private NotificationService notificationService;

    public GameSessionRunner(SudokuGame game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            //run implementation.
    }

    public void pauseGame() {
    }

    public void resumeGame() {
    }

    public void stopGame() {
    }
}

GameSession:
public class GameSession {

    private GameSessionRunner gameSessionRunner;
    private Thread gameThread;

    public GameSession(GameSessionRunner gameSessionRunner, Thread gameThread) {
        this.gameSessionRunner = gameSessionRunner;
        this.gameThread = gameThread;
    }

    public GameSessionRunner getGameRunner() {
        return gameSessionRunner;
    }

    public Thread getGameThread() {
        return gameThread;
    }
}


I don't see why this would need to be a spring component.

what is the issue you are having now ? and why do u want to create it as bean ?

The main reason is I wanted to use @Autowired NotificationService notificationService; inside GameSessionRunner but since it is not a Component @Autowired will not work. After searching online I found It can be achieved by either making GameSessionRunner a Component or passsing object of NotificationService during object creation of GameSessionRunner. I have achived the result using second way now I wanted to try Component way but not able to design it.


I wanted to use @Autowired NotificationService notificationService;
inside GameSessionRunner

For this you might consider making it a prototype component e.g.:
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Component
public class GameSessionRunner {

@Autowired NotificationService notificationService;
...

Then inject it via ObjectProvider:
@Autowired ObjectProvider<GameSessionRunner> gameSessionRunnerObjectProvider;

Then instantiate it like:
GameSessionRunner gameSessionRunner = gameSessionRunnerObjectProvider
                .getObject(<any additional paramaters>);


And how to regester GameSessionRunner bean?                              using BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor ?

please try the above code and see if it works. It involves the prototype component. I suggest you experiment some with it in a small application if this concept is unclear.
